# How can I use a LINQ select to populate a class from another object?

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
Question question = _questionsRepository.GetById(questionId);
```

I would like to do the following:

```
QuestionHeader questionDetail = _questionsRepository.GetById(questionId)
    .Select(m => new QuestionHeader { QuestionId = m.QuestionId })
```

But it gives me an error saying:

Models.Core.Question' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no 
extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'Models.Core.Question' 
could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I populate questionDetail ?

Comment: your `GetById` returns a single object `Question` which doesn't implement any `IEnumerable<T>`...

Comment: `QuestionHeader questionDetail = new QuestionHeader { QuestionId = question.QuestionId };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just do this (assuming you actually want to hit the database)?

```
QuestionHeader questionDetail = new QuestionHeader()
{
    QuestionId = _questionsRepository.GetById(questionId).QuestionId
};
```

or

```
QuestionHeader questionDetail = new QuestionHeader() { QuestionId = questionId };
```

...or if you need the question as well:

```
Question question = _questionsRepository.GetById(questionId);
QuestionHeader questionDetail = new QuestionHeader() { QuestionId = questionId };
```

If you have individual objects and not collections, you don't need LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing the `System.Linq` namespace.

Make sure you have

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your source file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx), you must pass in an `IEnumerable<T>` parameter as a source.  Since you don't have an `IEnumerable<T>`, you can't call `Select`.